# Need .htaccess URL rewrites for a Xenforo migraton Transfer to vBulletin 5 Connect

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, vbulletin, xenforo

Since no one has replied to my request. I will make this as simple as possible. I want to redirect Xenforo threads to vBulletin threads. Here are my examples. I want all link like this to all redirect. Thanks.

This is the old link:

```
www.codeshrek.com/threads/list-of-extremely-useful-web-design-links-will-stay-updated.45/#post-87
```

This is the new link that I want the above to redirect to:

```
www.codeshrek.com/forum/resource-management/resource-center/93-list-of-extremely-useful-web-design-links-will-stay-updated
```

Thanks and let me know I appreciate it.

Comment: Can someone please respond to this. I simply need to know how to reverse the .htaccess code provided in the opposite way.

Comment: In the target URL, where does "93" come from?

Comment: It's a number that has to do with posts in vBulletin. The first URL structure is for Xenforo and the second which is the one you pointed out is for vBulletin. I've been searching on how to do this all day. If you could help me I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: This is ridiculous. Why isn't anyone helping?